# How to break the string into pieces and assign the values to the substrings preceding the number in the originial string

Tags: python, regex

I want to break the string into pieces (delimiters are space and `/`) and assign values to the sub-strings every time a float or int follows the string:

For example, the string could be:

'ABC 12/5 a1 b-2.5 c34.5d54'

Using this, I want the output as:

`somelist=['ABC', '12', '5']`, and 
`a=1, b=-2.5, c=34.5, d=54`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this script:

```
import re

s = 'ABC 12/5 a1 b-2.5 c34.5d54'
parts = re.findall('([a-z]+)(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|([^ /]+)', s)
somelist = [rest for (key, value, rest) in parts if key == '']
vars = dict((key, float(value)) for (key, value, rest) in parts if key != '')

print(somelist)
print(vars)
```

Output:

```
['ABC', '12', '5']
{'c': 34.5, 'd': 54.0, 'a': 1.0, 'b': -2.5}
```

The "variables" are in fact output as dictionary keys, which I think is more appropriate.

#### Explanation

This regular expression:

```
([a-z]+)(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|([^ /]+)
```

will somehow match anything that is not a space or slash. First it tries to match the part before the `|`:

```
([a-z]+)(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

This will match any sequence of letters followed by a number. The letters are captured in the first group (cf. the parentheses), and the number part in the second one. The number can optionally have a minus sign (`-?`) and/or a fractional part (`(?:\.\d+)?`), which is not captured in a separate group (hence the `?:`).

If that fails, the other part of the regular expression kicks in:

```
([^ /]+)
```

This captures anything up to the next delimiter into the third capture group.

Now `findall` makes a nice array of this, with each part ending up at the corresponding index of each sub array.

The two list comprehensions each take care of the two different cases and gather those results in either an array (where the third capture group was matched) or a dict (where the first two were matched).

Comment: Hi, Could you please explain this part? Sorry, I am a novice in regex.  The first ?: is a non-capturing but the last one captures, so I am a bit confused.                 (?:\.\d+)?

Comment: There is only one non-capturing group `(?:   )`, which concerns the decimal point an any digits after it. But it is captured as part of a bigger capture group that does not have the `?:`.